# Attach label to edge in graphviz when many labels are available

Tags: graphviz

Consider the following edge in graphviz

```
a -> b [weight=5, foo="Ding", bar="Dong", label="something"];
```

Now by default, `something` is printed on edge when I convert this file to graph image using `dot` command. How can I change it to `Dong` without replacing `bar` with `label`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. `foo` and `bar` are not standard properties, and even if you think that it could represent some variables, I don't believe that dot would have such a system, and therefore has no way to use it from the`label` field.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless you post-process.
E.g., you could output an svg file, add the foo and bar variables to a the edge href attribute, and then replace the label text automatically with, for example, javascript.